# Error in query for multiple fields

Tags: soql, error

When i write 'Select Id, Subject,Status from Task where Subject like \'%'+searchText+'%\'  OR Status like \'%'+searchText+'%\' Order By Subject,Status'; it is working but when i include OR ActivityDate like \'%'+searchText+'%\' .

I tried with  OR ActivityDate like \'%'+String. valueOf(ActivityDate)+'%\' but still the error occurs.I converted date to string and still no joy. Please help.

```
      // Apex  

  String qry ='Select Id, Subject,Status from Task where Subject like \'%'+searchText+'%\'  OR Status like \'%'+searchText+'%\' OR ActivityDate like \'%'+searchText+'%\' Order By Subject,Status,ActivityDate';

  SearchResults = Database.query(qry);


     <!-- Page-->

      <apex:pageblocktable value="{!SearchResults}" var="t" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(SearchResults))}" align="center">
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!t.Id}">{!t.Subject}</apex:outputLink>
        <apex:column value="{!t.Subject}"/>
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!t.Id}">{!t.Status}</apex:outputLink>
        <apex:column value="{!t.Status}"/>
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!t.Id}">{!t.ActivityDate}</apex:outputLink>
        <apex:column value="{!t.ActivityDate}"/>
```

Comment: `LIKE` operator doesn't work with a `Date` or `DateTime` field. What are you expecting with that? You can filter it from a date range

Comment: I want user should be able to search Task by Subject,Status, ActivityDate & by OwnerId . have done pagination with Search box and hence need to filter by the above fields .

Comment: No way dear.. `LIKE` operator is for `String` type. You can prompt user to select a date range and use it for the filter. That's the way normally web applications are following for date filters

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.How do i get to that date range ? So this means that OwnerId will also not work as LIKE is for String type only? Any modification if you would like to suggest.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [salesforce documentations](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm), `LIKE` operator will work only with `String` type fields.

> The LIKE operator is supported for string fields only.

So you can't filter for `Id` types nor `Date` types. For `Owner`, may be you have to filter with `FirstName`, `LastName` or some other mechanism based on your requirement. 
And for `Date` fields you can let user to select a date range and apply that in your query. Because Salesforce gives us plenty of Date literals and Date functions to work with SOQL.

1. [Date Formats and Date Literals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)
2. [Date Functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm)

e.g.
You can let user to select the month

```
<apex:selectList id="selectedMonthsOptn" value="{!selectedMonth}" size="1" label="Month:">
    <apex:selectOptions id="monthsOptn" value="{!monthValues}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Controller :

```
public Integer selectedMonth{get;set;}   
public List<SelectOption> getMonthValues(){
        List<SelectOption> months = new List<Selectoption>();
        months.add(new selectOption('0', ALL_MONTHS));
        months.add(new selectOption('1', 'January'));
        months.add(new selectOption('2', 'February'));
        months.add(new selectOption('3', 'March'));
        months.add(new selectOption('4', 'April'));
        months.add(new selectOption('5', 'May'));       
        months.add(new selectOption('6', 'June'));
        months.add(new selectOption('7', 'July'));
        months.add(new selectOption('8', 'August'));
        months.add(new selectOption('9', 'September'));
        months.add(new selectOption('10', 'October'));   
        months.add(new selectOption('11', 'November'));
        months.add(new selectOption('12', 'December'));      

        return months;
    }    

public String generateDynamicQuery(){
   String myquery = 'SELECT myfields FROM myObj WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH(convertTimeZone(myDateField))=' + selectedMonth+'';
   return myquery;
}
```

Likewise you can have `WEEK_IN_MONTH`, `DAY_ONLY()`, `CALENDAR_YEAR()` and lot of other functions to filter `Date` fields base on your requirement.

Enjoy it :)